# How can I add images in the table cell?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created a sandbox for the table, in that I want to add separate image for each row. How can I add this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/wkqjxk38z7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you try to achieve that?

1. You need to add the image to your data list, e.g. (see frozen yoghurt):

```
state = {
    order: "asc",
    orderBy: "calories",
    selected: [],
    data: [
      createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
      createData("Donut", 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
      createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
      createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0, "http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/38900000/-Frozen-Yoghurt-frozen-yogurt-38904380-289-300.jpg"),
      createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
      createData("Honeycomb", 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5),
      createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
      createData("Jelly Bean", 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0),
      createData("KitKat", 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0),
      createData("Lollipop", 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0),
      createData("Marshmallow", 318, 0, 81, 2.0),
      createData("Nougat", 360, 19.0, 9, 37.0),
      createData("Oreo", 437, 18.0, 63, 4.0)
    ],
    page: 0,
    rowsPerPage: 5
  };
```

2. You need to adapt your createData function (added img):

```
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein, img) {
  counter += 1;
  return { id: counter, name, calories, fat, carbs, protein, img };
}
```

3. You need to add a column to your table header:

```
const rows = [
  {
    id: "name",
    numeric: false,
    disablePadding: true,
    label: "Dessert (100g serving)"
  },
  { id: "calories", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Calories" },
  { id: "fat", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Fat (g)" },
  { id: "carbs", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Carbs (g)" },
  { id: "protein", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Protein (g)" },
  { id: "img", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Img" }
];
```

(Btw. these are columns, not rows. :))

4. You need to display the data in your table content:

```
<TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n.id)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={n.id}
                      selected={isSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox checked={isSelected} />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
                        {n.name}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.calories}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.fat}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.carbs}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{n.protein}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right"><img src={n.img} alt={n.name} width="50" /></TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
```

And that's it..